# How to constantly keep model loaded in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Well, the problem is as follows. I have models hierarchy as follows:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Class B < A
end

class C1 < B
end

class C2 < B
end
```

In one of the controllers I need to search for B, C1 or C2. 
Rails does it if the related models are loaded. 
So the sql query should (and will ideally) contain something like

```
B.find 224 
# => SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."type" IN ('B','C1','C2') AND "bs"."id" = 224 LIMIT 1
```

And that the exacly what is needed. However, it turns out that models are unloaded on each request and not loaded again(not sure for reasons of that).
In that case if the models are not in the memory, ActiveRecord will make query like

```
B.find 224 
# => SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."type" IN ('B') AND "bs"."id" = 224 LIMIT 1
```

If you will simply call for C1 or C2 before find their types will be included into sql

```
C1
B.find 224 
# => SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."type" IN ('B','C1') AND "bs"."id" = 224 LIMIT 1
```

I tried to load those models in the initializers. eval C1,  require 'app/models/c1.rb', require_dependancy 'app/models/c1.rb' but neither of those works. Actually, they all worked for one time. Only one time after server was started. I suspect that there will be no such problem under production environment, but it very annoying.

An Ugly solution is to call C1 and C2 after B definition, in that case it worked as expected, But, as I said already, it is ugly

```
class B < A
end
C1, C2
```

Any better Ideas?

Update moved to answer.

Comment: omg what a mess.  I would step back and reading a book like Agile Web Development with ruby on Rails or something.  throwing in " < from modelname" in the hope that the inheritance work work that way is a common misconception with RoR.  You actually need to use structures like STI(Single Table Inheritance) and polymorphism for stuff like that.  Ending up with this hack is a great way to know your missing some knowledge :)

Comment: Please, read the post more carefully. Problem exactly concerns STI.
Anyway it is solved in Rails 3.2 with ActiveReload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured out some sort of solution. It is not  very impressive, but it seems to be working:

I requires to add a hack to the ActiveSupport::Dependencies.

So here is the hack listing:

```
    #lib/system_hacks/active_support.rb
    module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
      module Dependencies #:nodoc:

        #this array contains all the constants that have to be constantly loaded
        mattr_accessor :constantly_loaded_files
        self.constantly_loaded_files = []

        #redefining the method, with additional line
        def remove_unloadable_constants!
          autoloaded_constants.each { |const| remove_constant const }
          autoloaded_constants.clear
          Reference.clear!
          explicitly_unloadable_constants.each { |const| remove_constant const }
          #a hack
          constantly_loaded
        end

        #will simply make a call for each constants
        #in that case they will be updated... but still in the memory
        def constantly_loaded
          constantly_loaded_files.each do |file|
            file.to_s.classify.constantize
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

And in the initializers a small file to load the hack and to assign an array of constants:

```
  #config/initializers/model_loader.rb
  require File.join(Rails.root, 'lib','system_hacks','active_support')
    module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
      module Dependencies #:nodoc:
        self.constantly_loaded_files = [A, B, C1, C2]
      end
    end
```

If you have any comments, I would happily listen for them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what this data structure is trying to achieve? I see the single table inheritance pattern set up in the model inheritance, but I can't see what the initial solution is that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Problem was with controllers. Whenever an instance of C1 was attempted to be presented as B, it fails, unless B class was explicitly loaded. so link like /bs/123 will return error, unless B class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off class-reloading in development, you can do that. In config/environments/development.rb, just make:

config.cache_classes = true

instead of the default false. That will turn off development-mode class reloading for all classes, which is kind of inconvenient. There's theoretically supposed to be a way to exempt only specific classes from development-mode class reloading, but it keeps changing from rails version to rails version, and often doesn't work quite right, and I haven't kept track of how to do it in current rails or if it works. I wouldn't be comfortable with your hacky attempt to implement that feature yourself via monkey patch -- the fact that Rails has tried to support this officially various ways in the past but failed indicates that it's tricky to get right, and you probably haven't.

HOWEVER. I don't think this is really what you're looking for. I think there's something screwy with your overall design, and turning off class reloading is just a workaround. But I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do or what's going on. ActiveRecord does support "single table inheritance" model class hieararchy -- but it seems as if you are trying to do "multiple table inheritance" instead.

I am *not certain* myself if AR supports multi-table inheritance or not -- I'd look for documentation on this, and if AR supports it, do it how it tells you to do -- and if AR does not support it, give up on the design unless you really want to get into the internals of AR and figure out how to make AR do it or write an extension to AR to do it. The fact that it almost sort of works might make me guess that AR supports multi-table inheritance, but you're missing some kind of configuration to tell it.

There is also the Rails "polymorphic association" feature, which may or may not be useful to you.

Basically, sorry not sure if AR can do what you want, but if I were you I'd only try it if I can find evidence that AR actually supports it -- even if you make it appear to work by turning off dev-mode class reloading, there are probably other weird bugs waiting for you if you're trying to do something AR doesn't support. AR is complicated code.

Comment: Cashing all the classes on each request takes toooo much time.... So, it can not be considered as acceptable solution.